# What are the most effective tools to manage multiple apache httpd instances?

Tags: apache

We have many Apache instances all over our intranet. Some instances run on the same machine. Some instances run on different machines.

I need a tool that can manage these instances from one central location.

- Get CPU stats
- Get Connection stats
- Stop/start Apache instances
- Get access to error log

I looked at webmin, but the documentation isn't too clear how it works. Without installing it I'd have trouble getting it to go.

Any recommendations?

Comment: You might get more mileage from serverfault.com since this technically isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used it myself, but I've seen people with monitoring requirements be very happy with [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/). Besides general health monitoring like CPU stats it has an extremely simple [Apache stats plugin](http://www.cacti.net/additional_scripts.php) that might do what you need:

> Script to get the requests per second and the requests currently being processed from 
>    an Apache webserver.

maybe you can put something together with that.